# Subdomain url-rewrite in web.config

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect

This is how i currently want to redirect my site to

when i try navigating to

```
 http://sub1.sitename.com it should redirect to sitename.com/newprojects/sub1
```

and the same for sub2

i tried using it like this but it ends up loading www.sitename.com

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
  <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^sub1\.sitename\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="sitename\.com/newprojects/sub1/" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="Redirect1" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^sub2\.sitename\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
         <action type="Redirect" url="sitename\.com/newprojects/sub2/" redirectType="Permanent" />   </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: the answer below looks correct - you should either give some marks or add a comment saying why not... someone has taken the time to answer your question, give some respect back

Answer (score 1):

You could try matching all the URL's and then filtering based on what you want to redirect.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="sub1 redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub1\.site\.com(/)?$"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/newprojects/sub1/" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="\newprojects\sub1\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

this worked for me.